# How Can I setup WP CLI on Windows development machine running AMPPS?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, updates, customization, wp-cli

I want to setup WP CLI. On the [home page](http://wp-cli.org/) it says that it needs a UNIX like operating system.

I am running windows 7 for development but I could probably setup a virtual Ubuntu box or something. Would I run that alongside my existing ampps setup or would I need to setup a new local server inside the inux box or how would it work. And are there other options. I have seem that [running it with composer](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/wiki/Alternative-Install-Methods) seems to be an option, in fact as far as I can tell it's the only mention of windows on the website. Are there any tried and tested setups that would work for windows users.

Comment: Try installing msysgit or git bash, and install it (and run it) from there. Most features should work on a Windows machine

Comment: Thanks ... I ended up going with vagrant, which might be a bit overkill but I can appreciate what you're suggesting ... might try it if vagrant gets the better of me ... not exactly windows friendly any of this stuff

Answer (score 4):

Installing wp-cli through Composer is the way to go. For instance:

1. `$ cd C:\`
2. `$ composer create-project wp-cli/wp-cli --no-dev`
3. Copy the path to the bin directory inside the wp-cli directory (something along the lines of `C:\wp-cli\bin`)
4. Add copied path to the Windows Path variable ([tutorial](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm))

Exit all CMD's (or git bash) and reopen them. Now go to one of your WordPress installs and type `wp core version`. You should get the WP version

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to install [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#using-the-installer) and then install [wp-cli](https://packagist.org/packages/wp-cli/wp-cli) .  Under [Alternative-Install-Methods](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/wiki/Alternative-Install-Methods#installing-via-composer) it says to use `wp-cli/bin/wp.bat`, although I didn't like typing that path.

After installing in the manner mentioned, I created a wp.bat in my WordPress root along side wp.phar with the following contents:

```
@ECHO OFF
php "wp-cli/php/boot-fs.php" %*
```

Seems to work for what little I use it.

Comment: I also wrote a post about Azure with wp cli that may shed some additional light:
https://codesnob.wordpress.com/2015/06/09/testing-wordpress-on-azure/